# Chrome error **ERR_SPDY_TRANSPORT_SECURITY** only on mobile device

Tags: browser, chrome-for-android

I'm trying to brows one website in my SAMSUNG GRAND MAX mobile, using Chrome/ UC browser etc.
it shows below error

```
This webpage is not availale
ERR_SPDY_TRANSPORT_SECURITY
```

but same website is working fine on Desktop's Chrome browser.

Comment: Have you tried flushing sockets on chrome browser? Can't say for sure why this is happening on  mobile, but have  you updated your mobile browsers of late?

Comment: no I don't flushed sockets and also I'm not update Chrome browser. Now I'll do these things then let you know..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`SPDY`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPDY) is a protocol of chrome browser developed by Google. It was designed to load web pages faster and to improve web security.
However this protocol has been [deprecated](https://techcrunch.com/2015/02/09/google-starts-fading-out-spdy-support-in-favor-of-http2-standard/) in favour of the HTTP/2 Standard.

> Google’s servers will likely support SPDY quite a bit longer than its
>   browser, but in the long run, it will likely completely shut of SPDY
>   support there, too.

Possible reasons may therefore be an outdated browser, or perhaps firewall settings (if you have installed a firewall on your device etc)

**Possible ways to resolve this error:**

1. Updating the browser

   - First and foremost, update the browser and check if the same error shows. Usually latest build would have fixed bugs from previous builds.
2. Flush sockets in your browser:

   - Visit this url in your Chrome browser: `chrome://net-internals/#sockets`
   - Select "Flush sockets" in top right screen (drop down arrow)
3. Clearing hosts  cache

   - To clear hosts cache of chrome, visit this url; `chrome://net-internals/#dns` and tap on Clear host cache button

Comment: Thanks your first trick worked , I updated device Chrome app...!